# How to call the base class method in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods

I am working on a C++ program. For one of the use case, I have a class which is derived from its template class. So, I'm wondering how we can call the base class method inside the derived class method?

Example:

```
template <typename base>
struct derived : public base
{
    void aFunction()
    {
        // need to call a base function() here
    }
};
```

One of the way could be something like `base::aBaseFunction()`, but I am not sure?

I am new to OOP programming, so looking forward to learning a new concept through this problem statement.

Comment: Or `this->aBaseFunction();`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because unqualified name lookup doesn't check dependent bases.

Comment: Why "I am not sure"? Did something bad happen when you tried?

Comment: @molbdnilo didn't face any error as such with `base::aBaseFunction()`

Comment: @Jabberwocky not facing problem doesn't necessarily mean it is the correct way, I want to understand the underlying concept in this particular case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to explicitly use the base's member, make the type explicit like you found:

```
template <typename base>
struct derived : public base
{
    void aFunction()
    {
        base::function();
    }
};
```

If you would rather have the usual unqualified-lookup behaviour, make `this` explicit instead:

```
template <typename base>
struct derived : public base
{
    void aFunction()
    {
        this->function();
    }
};
```

Both of these behave exactly like they do in non-templates.